# Adding library files in WebStorm IDE

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express, webstorm

I am running a MEAN (MongoDB, Express, AngularJs, Nodejs) project in WebStorm IDE, i have included the required library files at time of starting my project.

After including the MongoDB connection, I need to include the Mongoose library in my project.

I have searched all the options given in the WebStorm IDE but I can't find the way.

Please tell me the way for including the library files in my project using WebStorm IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebStorm opens the folder of your file system. Click on open and select your folder. In order to get mongoose library, navigate to your project folder in command prompt and, use

> npm install mongoose

This will install mongoose in your `node_modules` folder.
Then wherever you want to use mongoose, just say `require("mongoose")`.

Answer (score 1):

Altought I prefer to use the CLI as @Bhoomi pointed out, there is a way to do it directly from the IDE.

Just open `Setting/Node.js and NPM`, clic `Install` button and you will get a list of available packages, so just install one of them (`mongoose` in this case) and voilá, WebStorm installs the package right under `node_modules` in your project (if the folder isn't already there then is created).

Comment: isn't there a way to use contents of package.json to get it to install modules? I've seen some IDE's that do that

Comment: The only way I can think of is to run it from a Grunt task, which is now directly supported by the IDE, but I haven't test it yet. If you come with something else please tell me, I'm very interested :)

Comment: I was working on one tutorial that had me download the a repo from github. This included a pacakge.json. I cd'd to the project and just ran npm install and it seems to have got everything in the package.json.

Comment: Yes sure, that is the customary way to do it (I do it myself like that), but have you found a way to do it directly within the IDE itself?

Comment: Only in the command terminal. This is what I was looking for, as previously I was installing every package by hand

Comment: Ok, this is unrelated to the question itself, then. However, if you find a way to do it directly just comment here, thanks.